# Aws KInesis Terraform - How to connect Data Streams to Data Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to create using terraform, Kinesis datastream and data firehose, and connect them (as pipeline). When I use the UI, when I go to firehose I can go to source->Kinesis stream, and pick the kinesis stream I created. But I want to do it using terraform.

This is the code to create kinesis stream (I took it from the official kinesis docs):

```
resource "aws_kinesis_stream" "test_stream" {
  name             = "terraform-kinesis-test"
  shard_count      = 1
  retention_period = 30

  shard_level_metrics = [
    "IncomingBytes",
    "OutgoingBytes",
  ]

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
  }
```

And this is the code for data firehose:

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "test_cluster" {
  domain_name = "firehose-es-test"
  elasticsearch_version = "6.4"
    cluster_config {
    instance_type = "t2.small.elasticsearch"
  }
  ebs_options{
    ebs_enabled = true
    volume_size = 10
  }

}

resource "aws_iam_role" "firehose_role" {
  name = "firehose_test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "test_stream" {
  name        = "terraform-kinesis-firehose-test-stream"
  destination = "elasticsearch"
/*
  s3_configuration {
    role_arn           = "${aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn}"
    bucket_arn         = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}"
    buffer_size        = 10
    buffer_interval    = 400
    compression_format = "GZIP"
  }
*/
  elasticsearch_configuration {
    domain_arn = "${aws_elasticsearch_domain.test_cluster.arn}"
    role_arn   = "${aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn}"
    index_name = "test"
    type_name  = "test"

    processing_configuration {
      enabled = "true"

    }
  }
}
```

So how can I connect them, is the something like ${aws_kinesis_stream.test_stream.arn} ? or something similar?

I used the official docs of [aws_kinesis_stream](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_stream.html) and [aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.html) (elasticsearch destination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the `kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream]` documentation. Acroll past the examples to the [Argument Reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.html#argument-reference) section, and you'll see this:

> The kinesis_source_configuration object supports the following:
>
> kinesis_stream_arn (Required) The kinesis stream used as the source of the firehose delivery stream.
>      role_arn (Required) The ARN of the role that provides access to the source Kinesis stream.